# Python, find components in dictionary that match a rule

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have a python dictionary that looks like this one:

```
dict = { '1': 0.002, '2': 0.211, '3': 0.574 .....(a lot of values) }
```

I am looking for good way to find which numbers sum equals a specific number.

Also, I would like to add the feature of choosing how many numbers to be calculated.

For example, if I enter `("0.213", 2)` the function would return `'1', '2'`.

Comment: Do you have any more information on the values? If two arbitrary values sum to some other arbitrary value is only checkable by summing every two values and look if the sum matches the searched value.

Comment: The general problem (for an arbitrary number of summands) is known as [the subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and is NP-complete.

Comment: Can there be more than one combination that yields the sum 0.213?

Comment: Ill give some more information that can helps.

There are 50 values, 6 of them needs to match a specific sum for the function to return them. 

Its always 50 values and the same sum that 6 of them needs to match it (but the values themselves change)

There could be a lot of combinations that match that sum..

Comment: 50 choose 6 is 15,890,700 sums of 6 numbers. This is doable but it may take a couple seconds or maybe even longer for Python (especially if you want to store all the possible subsets as tuples, that's potentially a lot of memory...and will be slow). I believe it can be optimized through Dynamic Programming however, by reusing the sums of smaller subsets of numbers to quickly calculate the sums of larger subsets that include the subsets.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to brute-force your way through all possible combinations. [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.combinations) was made for that:

```
import itertools
for comb in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), r):
    if sum(d[k] for k in comb) == target:
        return comb  # or add to a result list, if you want them all
```

where `d` is your dictionary, `r` is the number of values to be selected and `target` is the target value.

Although it's probably not a great idea to use `==` when comparing floats. Use at your own discretion.

Comment: I don't think he HAS to brute-force it, but yes this is one way. Dynamic programming can be used to optimize this by computing the sums of subsets of subsets only once. And for a set of 50 numbers, for subsets of size 6, it's probably best to make this a generator function instead using the `yield` keyword.